# JS slidetoggle on UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I am trying to slidetoggle ul's. But I stuck.

Here is my question:

Those codes are working:

```
    <div class="splitleft" onclick="toggle_item(b)">
        <?php echo $admin_logs ?>
        <ul class="menu" id="b">
            <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_all"><?php echo $admin_logs_desc ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_player"><?php echo $admin_watch_players ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_admins"><?php echo $admin_watch_admins ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script>function toggle_item(e){$(e).slideToggle();}</script>
```

But I don't want it. I want like this:

```
<ul class="menu" onclick="toggle_item(b)" id="b">
    <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_all"><?php echo $admin_logs_desc ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_player"><?php echo $admin_watch_players ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_admins"><?php echo $admin_watch_admins ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Can some one help me :) I'm really not good on js..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UL item does not contain any "space" on the page if the LI items inside are not visible. Therefore clicking will not do anything if the event is attached to the UL.

You need to attach the event to something that the user can actually click on. Without any code to clarify this all I can do is speculate...

HTML:

```
<div class="splitleft">
    <?php echo $admin_logs ?>
    <a id="ulOpener" href="#">Click me to open the UL</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="b">
        <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_all"><?php echo $admin_logs_desc ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_player"><?php echo $admin_watch_players ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_admins"><?php echo $admin_watch_admins ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('#ulOpener').click(function() {
        $('#b').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for explanation of why this won't work exactly as OP wants. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDmFH/) to show what you described.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery. There is an easy approach to this. In your `<head>` tag add this `<script>`:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#b').click(function( jqEvt ) {
        $(this).find('li').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Further explaining the bits and pieces:

`jQuery(function($){...})` is a short and sure form of `$(document).ready(function(){...})`. The parameter passed to the function is the jQuery object. This version ensures that you'll use the jQuery framework should another use the `$` variable.

`$('#b')` I hope you have enough knowledge to understand this. If not, this is your selector that causes jQuery to select your unsorted list element. Actually it picks the last element with attribute `id="b"`, although there should be only one. Everything else would be malformed HTML.

`.click(function( jqEvt ) {...})` binds an event listener for click events to the selected elements. The `jqEvt` parameter is a standardized event object.

`$(this).children().slideToggle();` The `this` context object is AFAIK identical to `jqEvt.target`, so it'll be your `div` tag. Since you are asking to collapse the `li` tags, you can select those with the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method. It takes another selector to match all succeeding elements against.

Comment: Working on DIVs.. but does not workig on ULs :(

Thats exactly my problem..

Comment: +1 correct answer. However, it is best practice to put all javascript at the bottom of the body elements (where possible). This enables faster page load.

Comment: @AlihanPehlivan please post a JSFiddle of your code.

Comment: Problem is not solved yet, just i want when i click UL, LI classes must be closed, when i click again LI classes must be appear..

Comment: @AlihanPehlivan I am confused. When the `DIV` is clicked, you want all the `LI` tags within the `UL` container to collapse? That's easy too. But please clarify your question.

Comment: @Derija93 Yes, this is exactly what i want. DIV. I tried extra DIV(no css) tag but interestingly does not working. Like this.  

<div id="b"><ul class="menu"><li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_all"><?php echo $admin_logs_desc ?></a></li><li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_player"><?php echo $admin_watch_players ?></a></li><li><a href="index.php?content=admin&page=show_logs_admins"><?php echo $admin_watch_admins ?></a></li></ul></div>

Comment: @AlihanPehlivan Your code does not reflect that. It shows that the `ul` tag is identified with `#b`. However, updated answer... that should help.

Comment: Here is jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93nKc/